# href link in anchor tag not getting triggered when viewed using tablet view

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Below is the link to an issue that I am facing. On normal chrome browser, on clicking the rectangle the message box is shown and the link is redirected to google.com. But if I the same thing is tried after changing the user agent on chrome to simulate ipad/iphone, the javascript does get called but it does not goto the href link.

https://jsfiddle.net/prkjg/

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <a ng-href="www.google.com"class="rectangle" data-ng-click="click()">{{message}}</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Missing a space here `ng-href="www.google.com"class="rectangle"`. Should be `ng-href="www.google.com" class="rectangle"`

Comment: Could you please update your jsfiddle? It doesn't match to the code in your question. In the jsfiddle there was a problem with the dependency to "ngTouch". If I remove it, the message will be shown.